# Происхождение слова "чифирь"

Tags: этимология

Откуда появилось слово "чифирь"? Нашёл в сети, что пишут и твёрдо — "чифир". Интересно ещё узнать, какой вариант более распространённый и где распространён тот, а где другой.

Comment: Англоязычная статья в Википедии (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chifir%27) ссылается на "чихирь" как возможный первоисточник.

Comment: Мне кажется, то, что написано в английской версии об этом, взято из русской. Там то же самое и даже больше. ;)

Comment: Существует несколько мнений о происхождении слова:
от «чихирь» — крепкого кавказского вина;
от сибирского областного слова «чихирь» — испорченного, скисшего вина; вообще любого дурманящего вещества неясного, тёмного (по цвету) происхождения и вида;
от слова «чагир», которым назывались в Восточной Сибири чайные суррогаты.

Comment: Эти версии я видел, но надеялся на что-то более достоверное: какую-то ещё версию или подтверждение одной из этих.

Answer (score 5):

Мужики! Если вам попадутся старые железные баночки советских времён из под чая - Грузинский чай ЕКСТРА (чрез "Е"(!), так как в таких баночках чай выпускался в Одессе), то на торце такой железной баночки вы увидите на  чёрном фоне заварочного чайничка три больших белых буквы ЧФР, причём буквы Ч и Р вписаны в пустые пространства буквы Ф. Такие баночки стояли на прилавках рядами и покупателю было видны ЧФР, что означало ЧАЕРАЗВЕСОЧНАЯ ФАБРИКА!

Точно такие же три буквы, с таким же изображением Ч и Р внутри Ф, одесская чаеразвесочная фабрика ставила и на бумажных упаковках с индийским чаем сорт 1 (125 г, 95 коп.) — чай со слоном.

Мне кажется, что эта версия ЧИФИРя наиболее объяснима.

С уважением, Юрий

**Дополнение** от grizzly (надеюсь, автор ответа не будет возражать):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Фабрика очень старая. Я не знаю, когда появились надписи чФр, но гипотеза на редкость интересная, хотя и любительская. Поддерживаю.

Comment: Только я не совсем понял, чем подтверждается, что ЧФР означало именно "чаеразвесочная фабрика". Я верю, что Вы знаете, на чём это основывается; просто хочется тоже это понимать и не сомневаться в этом.

Comment: Всем привет! Прямо на баночке и на бумажных пакетах  с чаем так и написано - чаеразвесочная фабрика или чайорозважувальна фабрика (м. Одеса). Спасибо ЮГ.

Comment: Спасибо, Юрий!)

Comment: Спасибо за фотографию с ЧФР! Спасибо за поддержку мнения! С Уважением, Юрий.

Comment: Для информации высылаю фото из своей коллекции

Comment: Высылаю «железную баночку» и бумажную упаковку ЧФР! С Уважением, Юрий.

Answer (score 1):

На старой платформе сайта я помещал исследование **"Вариации букв Ц-Ч "** , в котором показал этимологию слова <<**ЧИФИР**>> в разрезе феномена замены **Ц** на **Ч** . Но , после перехода сайта на новую платформу , раздел **ИССЛЕДОВАНИЯ** был удалён со всеми публикациями , включая и мои три . Там я объяснил , что <<**ЧИФИР**>> это очень-очень крепкий чай без сахара . Чифирят в местах лишения свободы , где проблемы со спиртным , но чай не запрещён (чифир даёт некоторый "кайф") . Однако <<**ЧИФИР**>> употребляют и для согрева в холодный сезон лесорубы , геологи и работники других профессий , связанных с работой "на природе" . (Относительно лесорубов я могу засвидетельствовать лично , как бывший работник лесной отрасли .)  Однако , *настоящий* <<**ЧИФИР**>> это чай , настоянный на водке , - этим напитком на фронтах ВОВ поднимали свой боевой дух штрафники Рокоссовского . Теперь об этимологии . <<**ЧИФИР**>> это от слова <<**ЦИФРА**>> с заменой **Ц** на **Ч** (*по такой замене я развернуто давал и другие примеры и этимологии  в той исчезнувшей публикации* ) . Во **время оно** упаковки чая не были столь красочными и с причудливо-экзотическими названиями , как сейчас . *На упаковках чая в старые времена ставились строчно цифровые обозначения , по которым можно было узнать откуда чай , какого сорта ,  когда собран или расфасован и другую информацию .* То есть , в сленге чай ассоциировался с <<ЦИФРОЙ>> : **Ц**ИФРА - **Ч**ИФРА - ЧИФИР .

Comment: Спасибо большое, следопыт! Только как подтвердить правильность того, что Вы сказали? Откуда у Вас уверенность в этой версии?

Comment: @Артём Луговой . О том , что на упаковках чая ставились комбинации цифр , содержащие информацию о продукте , я ещё тогда обнаружил в интернет-материалах по истории чая . К сожалению , я не сохранил ссылки . Попробуйте найти это сами , работая с интернет-поиском .

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю неважным, от «любителя» или «профессионала» исходит (уже «озвученная» здесь) версия происхождения слова «чифирь» (от аббревиатуры ЧФР - чаеразвесочная фабрика). Гораздо важнее то, что она имеет серьезные основания.

1. Торговать чаем в розницу удобнее, когда продукт расфасован. Вес чая в упаковке и его качество (происхождение, отсутствие примесей) проконтролировать непросто. Покупатель готов довериться надписям только на «фирменной» упаковке. Вот почему появились предприятия по расфасовке чая. Появились давно и было их в стране немало. Назывались они шаблонно «чаеразвесочная фабрика», а на (малоразмерной) упаковке - «ЧФР», плюс имя владельца или наименование места нахождения фабрики. Примеров тому множество и [вот](http://www.gnpc74.ru/culture?layout=edit&id=87) один из них.
2. Нет ничего проще, чем разбавить (водой) спиртное при его продаже в розлив. Поэтому покупатель предпочитал приобретать такой продукт в бутилированном виде. Розливом алкоголя занимались «ликеро-водочные заводы» (читай «ЛВЗ»), коих в стране было много. И даже больше, чем ЧФР (вспомним расхожее «чай не водка, много не выпьешь»).

Интернет просвещает нас:

«В 1936 году в СССР был принят государственный стандарт, в соответствии с которым чистая водно-спиртовая смесь получала наименование «водка». Международным термином слово «vodka» стало в 1950-х годах.
Теперь о крышках... Ближе к 1950-м крышечка для укупорки бутылки с водкой стала низкой, делали ее из алюминиевой фольги. Низкие крышки для водки, называемые в народе «бескозырки» за свисающее ушко для открывания, использовались вплоть до 1970-х годов. В 1980-е козырек у алюминиевой крышечки убрали, и пробку теперь приходилось отгрызать зубами, срезать ножом, тыкать вилкой и прочими колющими и режущими предметами. На такой крышечке, бывало, указывался ГОСТ или несколько букв, обозначающие название водки. Например, П – «Пшеничная», Р – «Русская», ОМ – «Особая Московская».

Фото таких крышечек легко найти в сети (ищем «старые пробки от водочных бутылок»). Заслуживают внимания те из них, на которых выбиты буковки «ЛВЗ» и наименование завода или города, где завод расположен. Это прямая параллель с аббревиатурой ЧФР.

В этом месте можно было бы поставить точку, но к теме «ЛВЗ» нашлось кое-что и «на закуску»...

Любопытна цитата [отсюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7): «В 1949 году начались поставки водки «Ливиз» (Ленинградский СНХ) на экспорт в Восточную Европу и США».

Похоже, что автор названия товарного знака «Ливиз» (в 1949 году) как минимум придерживался той же версии происхождения слова «чифирь», что предложена здесь Юрием, а как максимум — точно знал, что «чифирь» это ЧФР и ни что иное.

Comment: Спасибо!*******